# Where should I put the Custom Validators in Rails 5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to add an email custom validators for my app; However, where should I place the custom validator? (I really do not want to place this validator class inside the model) Is there a cli generator for validator?

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html

```
class EmailValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    unless value =~ /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\z/i
      record.errors[attribute] << (options[:message] || "is not an email")
    end
  end
end

class Person < ApplicationRecord
  validates :email, presence: true, email: true
end
```

What's the convention location/path for custom validator?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I put them in `/app/validators/email_validator.rb` and the validator will be loaded automatically.

Also, I don't know if it's your case but you should replace this in your form. If so, a first validation is made before the user reach your controller.

```
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %>
    <%= f.text_field :email, required: true %>
  </div>
```

By :

```
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %>
    <%= f.email_field :email, required: true %>
  </div>
```

Comment: is that the convention in rails? and will it be auto loaded?

Comment: Apparently [SO:5263239](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5263239/where-should-rails-3-custom-validators-be-stored),[SO:35953656](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35953656/where-exactly-do-i-put-autoload-path-for-custom-validator-in-config-application)

Comment: Thanks for the additional info. I am using api only rails. :D

Comment: If you are using spring you have to restart it in order to load the new path

Comment: `spring stop` was necessary for me in Rails 5.2, otherwise it wasn't picked up.

Comment: In Rails 5 applications the validator should be in the app/lib folder because all code inside the app folder is autoloaded in dev and eager loaded in prod. And most importantly it is autoreloaded in development so you don't have to restart server each time you make changes. So in Rails 5 applications the validator should be in `app/validators/email_validator.rb`

Answer (score 5):

##### Rails 6

`app/models/validators/` is also a sensible directory to house validators.

I choose this directory over others such as `app/validators` since the validators are context-specific to `ActiveModel`

*app/models/person.rb*

```rb
class Person < ApplicationRecord
  validates_with PersonValidator
end
```

*app/models/validators/person_validator.rb*

```rb
class PersonValidator < ActiveModel::Validator
  def validate(record)
    record.errors.add(:name, 'is required') unless record.name
  end
end
```

*config/application.rb*

```rb
module ...
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.load_defaults 6.1

    config.autoload_paths += Dir[File.join(Rails.root, 'app', 'models', 'validators')]
  end
end
```

*Specs for the validators would be placed in* `spec/models/validators/`

Comment: Note - if you design your rails app with other subdirectories, you can use `**` to also encapsulate those.

    `Dir[File.join(Rails.root, 'app', 'models', '**', 'validators')]`

Answer (score 1):

My validator did not loaded automatically. At least is not showing when I type in the console:

```
> ActiveSupport::Dependencies.autoload_paths
```

So, I put in my config/application.rb, this line:

```
config.autoload_paths += %W["#{config.root}/lib/validators/"]
```

Comment: `lib/` folders are not autoloaded. They removed lib autoload from rails 5.
You should create this folder and place validators there.
`app/validators/`
Then they will be autoloaded, so you don't need to make any setup in config.autoload_paths.

Answer (score -3):

In rails 6 I had to put them in `/app/models/concerns` for them to autoload

Comment: This is definitely not where they should be.